# Button in InfoPath to start a workflow (Out of the box)

Tags: list, workflow, infopath, list-form

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to start a workflow through an infopath button?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/is-there-a-way-to-start-a-workflow-through-an-infopath-button)

I have a client that wants to start a workflow on a list item from the InfoPath form. I haven't actually met with him to discuss his request and am merely doing some preliminary research based on the details supplied by his email.

Said client has a rudimentary knowledge about the inner workings of SharePoint and programming in general. That said, I consider myself a fairly competent coder, but am fairly new to SharePoint.

Now, what I understand from his correspondence is that he wants a button on the edit form of an existing list that will kick off a workflow for said item without submitting it. This also needs to happen out of the box, as I'm merely an intern within my current organization and am not allowed by policy to do any custom coding solutions. I do not yet understand the business process for which this will be necessary.

Now, considering my questionable knowledge about SharePoint, I somehow came under the impression that a workflow will not start on an item that is not checked in. Is this true? Is an item even checked out while already existing and open in the edit form? Lastly, is it possible to add a button out of the box to an InfoPath form that will start a workflow?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should refer to this link.. same problem was asked before..

[Is there a way to start a workflow through an infopath button?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19673/is-there-a-way-to-start-a-workflow-through-an-infopath-button)

Comment: It it helps you then dont forget to mark as Help or as Answer..

Answer (score 2):

you can create one filed yes or No (Default put No) in same list, then after you create one designer workflow when the item value is yes start workflow condition lie this    --

**Designer workflow**  --

if field isequalto yes

start approval workflow

Finally open infopath add button rule (when button click value chage to yes). once yes workflow started. any clarification ask me Thanks.

Comment: Can you change the value of a column in a SharePoint list from Infopath without submitting?

Comment: even if you submit the form workflow not triggered, once value change the filed value (means button click) wait for start a workflow.  Workflow start type is when item is updated.